# Bootstrap not loaded when publishing Core MVC site to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

i have created a asp .net core web application using available template,i made changes to bootstrap in wwwroot and deployed to azure. the changes which i made are working fine locally but it is not reflecting in azure though i can see in the output window the bootstrap is updated while publishing . here is my reference to bootstrap file.

```
    <environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Map.css" asp-append-version="true" />

</environment>

    <environment names="Development">
    <script src="../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="../lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
    </script>
    <script src="../js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: `@RenderSection("scripts", false)` and `<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` remove dot ..try this one

Comment: i tried making these changes but nothing worked, still facing same issue.